# Should I mention on my CV that I want to get a buy-to-let house?

Tags: resume, job-change

I am changing careers and therefore will be starting from the bottom again.
The new job I am applying for will be in a business call center for a bank and I am hoping to work my way up again.

A goal of mine has always been to get a [buy to let house](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buy_to_let). From my savings from my current job in retail I have managed to get on the property ladder and I am hoping to get one or maybe two BTL's next year.

In my CV do you think I should include this goal? If I do, it will be going at the end under hobbies and goals.
I think it sounds impressive, resourceful and ambitions, but possibly a little forced?
Do you think including it could do any harm?

Comment: Tell them that in the interview, not in the resume'

Comment: Yes, it could do harm - anything that makes an employer wonder "will they be able to fully focus on the job?" is a potential negative.

Answer (score 9):

> In my CV do you think I should include this goal?

No. Unless this is directly related to the job you are seeking, it shouldn't be on the CV.

In my experience as a hiring manager, I'm not interested in applicants' life goals when I quickly scan through their CV/resume.

If it's impressive, resourceful, and ambitious, you could probe for interest during the interview itself.

But as AdamV points out in his comment, be careful. A hiring manager might well wonder if your attention will be distracted by your personal goals (buy-to-let homes), and thus you would not be able to focus fully on the job being offered.